# How to remove only the last letter in string, python?

Tags: python, string, replace, letter

I am making a "Wordle" type of game in Python and wanted to remove the last letters you wrote when you press backspace and it worked in most cases but I have a problem if your word has the letter that are the same for example "start".

I tried using the `.replace()` function like this:

```
word = 'start'
new_word = word.replace(word[4], '', 1)
print(new_word)
```

But the result isn't `'star'`, but rather `'sart'`.
As you see it replaces the first 't' and not the last.
Does anyone know how to replace the last `'t'` but the solution needs to work on any case, like in `'aaaaa'` it just needs to replace the last `'a'`?

Comment: hint: `'start'[:-1] = 'star'`

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called "slicing": [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score -2):

Extract from the total length of the word the last character, like this for example:

word = 'start'

new_word = word[:len(word)-1]

print(new_word)

Answer (score -2):

```
word = 'start'
new_word = word.replace(word[1], word[4]) #replaces letter 1 with letter 4
new_word = new_word[:-1] #removes last letter
print(new_word)
```

Comment: There is no need for this line of code `new_word = word.replace(word[1], word[4])` he just need to slice the string.